# Primefaces 5 <p: calendar> does not display the option to select time

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Need to use the component p:calendar with the option to select the date and time (hours, minutes and seconds).

The problem is that the option to select the time is not displayed, only the option to select the date. I am using the following pattern "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss".

According to [primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml) no additional attribute is required for display of schedule options, only define the pattern.

```
<p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" value="#{calendarMB.date}" timeZone="GMT-3" />
```

Managed Bean

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CalendarMB implements Serializable {

    private Date date;

    // get/set
}
```

I performed the tests with primefaces 5.0 and 5.1

---

**Edit**

Discovered the cause of the problem. Conflicting versions of jquery. We have a template with the following code `<h:outputScript library="comum" name="javascript/jquery-1.10.2.js" />` By removing this import component worked as expected. Thank you all for the help

Comment: Strange. Does removing `timeZone` make any difference?

Comment: I removed the attribute timeZone and the problem persists. I also tested with other datePatterns (MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss)

Comment: Cannot reproduce (using PF 4.0, 5.0, 5.1)
Might the timepicker be hidden by CSS?

Comment: Long shot, but the only other difference is the id, Any changes if you give it an id? Anything in the logs? Could it be that some CSS is hiding the time selectors?

Comment: I added an id to the component and nothing has changed. 
The timepicker is not being hidden by css

Comment: Can't reproduce either. Did you try other browsers? Try also the calendar with only the pattern in the simplest page you have. Let's see if we can narrow the problem...

Comment: Discovered the cause of the problem. Conflicting versions of jquery.   We have a template with the following code 
`<h:outputScript library="comum" name="javascript/jquery-1.10.2.js" />`
By removing this import component worked as expected.   Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discovered the cause of the problem. Conflicting versions of jquery. 
We have a template with the following code `<h:outputScript library="comum" name="javascript/jquery-1.10.2.js" />` By removing this import component worked as expected. Thank you all for the help