# How to show timepicker on Primefaces Calendar component?

Tags: primefaces, calendar

I'm using Primefaces Calendar component to select date and time, but only date part is available. My code looks almost the same as the code from http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml (example "Datetime"), so I can't figure it out, what's wrong in my case. Any suggestion?

My code:

```
<p:calendar value="#{item.dateFrom}" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm" />
```

Comment: Same issue is being discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382626/primefaces-5-p-calendar-does-not-display-the-option-to-select-time

Comment: I see... the only difference is that I'm using PrimeFaces 4.0, but probably it doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Hours are represented by a capital H.

So your code has to be:

```
<p:calendar value="#{item.dateFrom}" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" />
```

... with capital H.

Comment: I believe HH or hh can be used. Anyway, even if I change that, nothing happens...

Answer (score 0):

There was a template in a  tag, so that template was in use and the time component was not displayed. By removing this tag, the problem disappears.